# sql exceptions when trying to insert duplicate records into the database

Tags: java, mysql, database, spring-boot, transactions

I have the below method which checks if a user exists and then adds it to the database if it does not exist.

```
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
public Optional<User> create(User user) {
Optional<User> userOptional = userRepository.findByEmail(user.getEmail());
if (userOptional.isPresent()) {
    return Optional.empty();
}
User savedUser = userRepository.save(user);
return Optional.of(savedUser);
```

}

two threads t1 and t2 are trying to save the same user with the same email(example@example.com). The following occurs:

t1 cant find user

t2 also cant find user

t1 adds user to database

t2 tries to add user to database but fails as record already exists and throws following error:

```
2019-10-02 18:28:43  WARN UKPC000029 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] 
o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper             : SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000 
2019-10-02 18:28:43 ERROR UKPC000029 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] 
o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper             : Duplicate entry 'example@example.com' for key 'UK_tcks72p02h4dp13cbhxne17ad' 
2019-10-02 18:28:43 ERROR UKPC000029 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.h.i.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl        : HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] 
2019-10-02 18:28:43 DEBUG UKPC000029 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.s.o.j.JpaTransactionManager            : Initiating transaction rollback after commit exception    
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [UK_tcks72p02h4dp13cbhxne17ad]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement   
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:296)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:253)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:536)
```

In order to get around this error I tried to use serializble isolation level
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)

However in the same scenario I got the following error:

```
2019-10-02 18:52:56  WARN UKPC000029 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper             : SQL Error: 1213, SQLState: 40001  
2019-10-02 18:52:56 ERROR UKPC000029 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper             : Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction    
2019-10-02 18:52:56 ERROR UKPC000029 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.h.i.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl        : HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not execute statement] 
2019-10-02 18:52:56 DEBUG UKPC000029 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.o.j.JpaTransactionManager            : Not closing pre-bound JPA EntityManager after transaction 
2019-10-02 18:52:56 DEBUG UKPC000029 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.s.o.j.JpaTransactionManager            : Initiating transaction rollback after commit exception    
org.springframework.dao.CannotAcquireLockException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not execute statement   
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:287)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:253)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:536)
```

I was under the impression that both transactions would be done 1 after the other?

The following link

[isolation explained](https://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/spring-transaction-isolation-tutorial)

*SERIALIZABLE isolation level is the most restrictive of all isolation levels. Transactions are executed with locking at all levels (read, range and write locking) so they appear as if they were executed in a serialized way. This leads to a scenario where none of the issues mentioned above may occur, but in the other way we don't allow transaction concurrency and consequently introduce a performance penalty.*

However both threads are still checking for the user email even though the 1st transaction hasnt finished? What is the best way to deal with this problem? Is using java locks acceptable in this case?

Comment: One option is to skip the check and just save the user directly and handle any thrown exceptions since it is the database that is doing the actual validation anyway. One thread will return the new user and the other will catch an exception and return empty

Comment: You really shouldn't validate uniqueness (or other database constraints) in your code. Especially in a multithreaded environment. Instead you need to deal with constraint-based exceptions.

Comment: i did it as i thought it would be cheaper than trying to do a write

Comment: Do you have a transaction manager bean?

Comment: i did not explicitly define a transaction manager bean